# Request for new users to prove they're human

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts

There have been plenty of "users" asking "questions" which turn out to be spam and advertising. Some examples include things like "Have The Body You Deserve?" and "Easy Ways to Lose Weight Fast".

EDIT: I have recently found a third example. This nearly confirms my suspicions: "We should view results fast?"

These are blatant advertising, and I suspect that a bot could be to blame. I'm requesting an addition to the account creation process which requires verification that you're human.

Comment: Make sure you flag those as spam when you see them!

Comment: I did, and I'm pretty sure they were removed.

Comment: Maybe I'm looking at it wrong, but wouldn't all anyone have to do is create account, prove that they are human and then put the bot to work using the login? I think the best that can be done is flag as you see them.

Comment: The request would prevent bots from signing up, though. That might help some of the problem.